# Angularjs to Angular Migration: factory prototype

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, factory

I am migrating from angularjs to angular. I already did a lot, but I am still stuck with factories and prototypes. Card represents a play card.

```
        function Card() {
            this.remoteId = 0;
            this.version = 0;
            this.name = "";
            this.stars = 0;
        }

       Card.prototype = {
            getFromRemote: getFromRemote,
            initFromRemote: initFromRemote,
            updateFromCard: updateFromCard,
            createImage: createImage,
           };


      return (Card);
     }
```

Now I am just wondering hhow to migrate it, because there are no more factories in angular. I was thinking about making the Card function a card interface like in the angular tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1. Do you think that is a good idea or do I miss something?
Any help or ideas would be appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of abstract class and constructor:

`abstract class` to get  functionality of prototype.

Initial value setting logic can go inside the `constructor`.
[playgrond-link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=32&ssc=11&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguAwsKAJggN4BQpCCokM8CUApgLYD2EDAkgQFwIB2AVyYgGUANwUq4aHEQA3UWACWLPr0HDREytRl0%20wJg140lfAOaTdtRJHxh1QkePKUADgJDIlsBGaUQAGJQLEwASsxsDAAUAJS8cixKRGSUlBAAFkpgAHSMrOxcCAC8CAAM2ggAvq4IHl4%20dVBmEHEkkpSwqmAsyAw5yCzm0ZnZsZU1pJMoaBh4hAgMAB7sfAQY2GDzKbX13r75UVyOmlAl5ZUKUMqqJ87nFZIGRibQZubnAOSflXbXd6IHpVJHtGl0%20DQBPAWFA2sQEB0EGABG5RHFKpQAPQAKgQbAygNgjGAEBUfAQg3MYOA5K6RgQBMYCGxmMkNUmfUQvlKfAYAHcENt0aRYDk3M0%20K1xuQgA)

```
 abstract class AbsCard {

  abstract remoteId: number;
  abstract version: number;
  abstract name: string
  abstract stars: number;

  public initFromRemote(): void {
    this.remoteId = 0;
  }

  public print() {
    console.log(this);
  }

}

class Card extends AbsCard {

  public remoteId: number = 0;
  version: number = 0;
  name: string = '';
  stars: number = 0;
  
  public constructor() { 
    super();
    /* other creation logic can come here */
  }
}

let c = new Card();
c.print();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that!

Comment: Now I thought more about it I have another question. I am a bit ashamed to ask it, but still confused from factories and angular... So do I put your suggested code in an service, as factories are now services in angular or in an component? Your answer would be appreciated!

Comment: the concept of creating custom object in angularJs has been abandoned in anuglar2+, only the concept of creating service is carried out, if you still want a service that creates a custom object for you, that's just an implementation it logicly.

In short you dont need factories to create custom objects in angular2+, specially since introduction of typescript and classes , you can either create independent objects  or have a service create object for you (incase creating object needs service data) .
In above example you are creating independent objects (not created by service).